# How to have multiple lists in Django CBV ListView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

In my app, I want to have an index page which will display two lists of objects, where both lists contain the same type of object (i.e, same Model).

In traditional function based views this is easy: I define two variables, assign them to querysets, and pass them into the context to my template where I can easily access them by name.

I'm still new to CBVs and it seems there is a lot of magic, a lot of things that are handled automatically. I understand how I can override the queryset for a ListView (which defaults to all objects for the given Model), but what I don't get is how to supply multiple querysets, so that my ListView can actually display two lists.

My only thought so far is to override self.object_list to be a tuple of two querysets, but that seems like it would make my template code less clear and I'm not even certain it would work.

Comment: ListView is written to handle a single list. The problem is that you would need to change a lot of code to support 2 lists. I would suggest copying the listView definition (https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6c1/django/views/generic/list.py) and change all the methods to handle 2 (or more) lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want to support pagination in your multiple lists view, I would suggest overwriting the get_context_data and get methods of your view class

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Get the context for this view.
    """
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
    queryset2 = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list2)

    context = {
        'paginator': None,
        'page_obj': None,
        'is_paginated': False,
        'object_list': queryset,
        'object_list3': queryset2
    }

    context.update(kwargs)

    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list1 = self.get_queryset1()
    self.object_list2 = self.get_queryset2()

    context = self.get_context_data()
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Sorry for the names (1 and 2) but you should place more descriptive whenever I placed names like "get_queryset1"

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm going to give something like this a shot. I've realized my use case is somewhat niche, so it's going to take a little more than what CBVs offer by default. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What is the difference between the items in both lists? If you're talking about a single list (i.e. queryset) which can be split in two by some of their properties, this should simply be done in the template itself.

For example, imagine you have a list of users, and you want to display them by gender, i.e. men in one list and women in the other. In this case simply return a single queryset like normally with the `ListView`, and then in the template put something like:

```
<h4>Male Users</h4>
<li>
    {% for user in users %}
    {% if not user.is_female %}<ul>{{ user.full_name }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</li>

<h4>Female Users</h4>
<li>
    {% for user in users %}
    {% if user.is_female %}<ul>{{ user.full_name }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't like this answer, it doesn't seem to make much sense outside the simplest of cases. Consider you had a Model, let's call it a BlogPost, with attribute of post_date and it has some tags. Now let's say on a certain template, you want to display all posts between two date ranges, and a separate list of all posts that are tagged with "blue". You are suggesting passing a queryset of those combined BlogPosts to the template, and letting the template sort them out?

Comment: Yeah, why not? The alternatives are a) running two separate queries on the database, with the exact same results and the added overhead of an extra query, and b) separating the lists in the view before sending them to the template, which is pretty much the same thing as I propose, with an extra list being created.

Comment: Of course, there are cases where this solution wouldn't work, but in any case where the filter criterion is as simple this is more than sufficient. Remember the KISS principle.